# How can I create a 3 dimension int with pointer in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, int

```
int b, c, d;
cin >>b>>c>>d; 
int **a[b];
for(int i=0;i<b;++i){
    *a[i]=new int[c];
    for(int j=0;j<c;j++){
        a[i][j]=new int[d];
    }
}
```

I would like to create a 3 dimension int.I think the problem is when I create the second dimension it is not a pointer and I can not create a 3th on it.

Comment: It's generally better to use a dedicated class that is backed by a single dimensional array. Look up "silly matrix" and then extend the code to 3D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @yacsha posted, you're better off using `<vector>` from the STL, rather than using raw pointers and `new` (or even pointers at all).

But, if creating a '3 dimension int' is really what you want, then you must declare your variables properly, allocate, then delete them:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int b, c, d;
    std::cin >> b >> c >> d;

    // declaring a variable to a pointer that points to a pointer ... etc.
    // really hard to maintain and read
    int*** a = new int**[b];

    for (int i = 0; i < b; ++i) {
        a[i] = new int*[c];

        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            a[i][j] = new int[d];

            for (int k = 0; k < d; k++)
                std::cin >> a[i][j][k];
        }
    }

    // using it like a normal 3d array would be used
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < d; k++)
                std::cout << a[i][j][k] << ' ';
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    // deleting is necessary after using them
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
            delete[] a[i][j];

    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
        delete[] a[i];

    delete[] a;
}
```

As you can see, this is a nightmare to maintain. It's much more easier to use `<vector>` because the container takes care of the memory allocation for you. If you don't want to use STL, atleast use `a[b][c][d]`, where `b`, `c`, `d` are `const` / `constexpr`.

This is how it looks like with `<vector>`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int b, c, d;
    std::cin >> b >> c >> d;

    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> threeDim(b, std::vector<std::vector<int>>(c, std::vector<int>(d, 0)));

    for (const auto x : threeDim) {
        for (const auto y : x) {
            for (const auto z : y)
                std::cout << z << ' ';
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

You could `typedef` / `using` to shorten `std::vector` if you find it too cumbersome to declare and init the 3d array, or you could resize it via loops.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare `a` as a `***a[b]` (pointer, to a pointer, to a pointer).

```
int ***a[b];
```

Comment: By doing so you have can transcend and become a [three star programmer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Comment: Would the downvoter of this answer please explain their downvote? I answered the question as asked. Yes, I too think that using tripple-pointers is dumb, but I do not understand why that warrants a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the standard stl, which is safer than using pointers, so I would have to declare the "vector template":

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
```

The code would look like:

```
vector<vector<vector<int>>> A;  
int b, c, d;
cin >>b>>c>>d; 
int i,j,k;
A.resize(b);    
for(i=0;i<b;++i){       
    A[i].resize(c);
    for(j=0;j<c;j++){
        A[i][j].resize(d);
        for(k=0;k<d;k++){
            // Optional inputs elements
            cout << "Input element " <<i<<","<<j<<","<<k<<": ";
            cin >> A[i][j][k];
        }
    }
}
```